# How to overwrite data in BigQuery table using apache beam in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have few thousand rows in BigQuery table and when running the pipeline using the below command -

```
| 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery('{0}:sample.table_name'.format(PROJECT),schema=schema,
   write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
```

and it throws the following error -

```
RuntimeError: HttpBadRequestError: HttpError accessing <https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/tokyo-botany-302620/jobs?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '400', 'content-length': '3
14', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-contr
ol': 'private', 'date': 'Fri, 02 Apr 2021 19:15:22 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value for type:  NUMERIC is not a valid value",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid value for type:  NUMERIC is not a valid value",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
> [while running 'WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/TriggerLoadJobsWithoutTempTables/TriggerLoadJobsWithoutTempTables']
```

Runtime env for Python is - `Python 2.7.16`

I want to overwrite the existing records in the table.

Please help

Comment: I changed the datatype of few fields from 'NUMERIC' to 'INTEGER', still the same error.

Comment: You can't overwrite data like this. In addition, python 2.7 runtime is no longer supported

Comment: In that case, what should be done? I don't have python3 env in GCP as well.

Comment: Based on error codes here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages, it seems to be a bigquery issue when you have something wrong with the schema? Based on https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric_types, DECIMAL is an alias for NUMERIC. Maybe you can try other types for the problematic fields?

Comment: I tried to change to different fields like INTEGER or FLOAT, still receive the same error -...
"message": "Invalid value for type:  INTEGER/FLOAT is not a valid value",
...